# Please take a look at my server print out to see if all looks well or if the repeating errors mean something is wrong

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, firewall

So it is not clear to me if my bitcoin server is syncing and all is fine or if the "potential stale tip detected, will retry extra outbound " message means I have to do something. Searching for that string does not actually provide me an answer. I thought Bitcoin full node install would be a bit more intuitive. Any help appreciated

**Solution Update:**
My server was not connecting to peers because my ROUTER had a FILTER, set to medium, that was just allowing in some popular known ports. When I set it to Low, My server then started to see peers immediately. Just weird how the router chose to implement this firewall this way. It did not honor the fact that I forwarded the port.

Answer (score 1):

The message

```
potential stale tip detected, will retry extra outbound peers
```

is associated with at least two situations:

- A firewall is blocking port 8333 and your node cannot communicate with peers.
- Problems with genesis block (delete blocks and chainstate directories and restart).

Comment: Thank you. It was in fact that my ROUTER had a FILTER, set to medium, that was just allowing in some popular known ports. When I set it to Low, My server then started to see peers immiedietely. Just weird how the router chose to implement this firewall this way. It did not honor the fact that I forwarded the port.